# How to create PartialFunction literal after 2.12.5?

Tags: scala

Since `PartialFunction.apply` is deprecated since Scala 2.12.5, how can I create a PartialFunction without declaring a new variable?E.g. I was able to do:

```
List(0).map(PartialFunction[Int,Int]{
  case 0 => 100
  case x => x*100
}.orElse{
  case 100 => 0
})
```

How to write the same thing in Scala 2.12.5 in one statement?

Comment: Both 2.12.5 and 2.12.7 give *"missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known."*?

Comment: I've been trying to write that in one statement, but I am afraid it's not possible. You need an intermediate val.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Sorry the type is not automatically deducted as in a val statement. I changed to a map function so it will automatically deduce.

Comment: Why not moving the `orElse` part into the original match? It is never used here anyway, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deprecation warning actually tells you what to do: *"use an explicit type annotation instead"*:

```
val f = ({ case 0 => 100; case x => x * 100 }: PartialFunction[Int, Int])
  .orElse[Int, Int]{ case 100 => 0 }
```

**Update**

Why the `apply` was deprecated (probably):

```
val pf = PartialFunction[Int, Int]{ case 100 => 42 }
pf.isDefinedAt(50)
// res2: Boolean = true
```

The problem is: it's a partial function that is implicitly cast into normal function, and then again wrapped into partial function. It completely loses all the information about where it is actually defined, so `isDefinedAt` returns `true` for all inputs.

Comment: Interesting. This works, although a little awkward TBH But I wonder why they determine `PartialFunction.apply` is deprecated

Comment: @texasbruce I assume it's because the `apply` method was essentially useless, and was abused all the time. The problem is that it takes a `(A) => B`. But if you use `PartialFunction[A, B]{ case blah => blah}`, then the `{case blah => blah}` part is *first* implicitly converted into  an `(A) => B`, and only then passed to `PartialFunction.apply`. So, essentially, you end up with a partial function implicitly cast into ordinary function and then again wrapped into partial function: a PF-F-PF-onion. That's just too much unnecessary overhead.

Comment: That's a valid reason, but they could have optimized it in the compiler as a special case I guess. Anyway thanks!

Comment: @texasbruce No, they couldn't, see update. Once you wrap everything into a `Function1`, you lose all the information about the domain of the definition. PF-F-PF onion behaves differently than the original PF, it throws different match exceptions, and has different domain. See update.

Comment: Ya I was just saying they could have optimized the compiler to directly casting when `PartialFunction.apply` is used instead of converting back and forth, but that will break the consistency I guess. Fair enough!